# Casting problem at CSWClientDemo of geotoolkit

Tags: error, geotools, csw-client

I tried  to test CSWClientDemo of geotoolkit but couldn't succeed.

Here is a casting problem:

```
  GetRecordsResponseType response = ((JAXBElement<GetRecordsResponseType>) um.unmarshal(is)).getValue();
```

The error I got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.geotoolkit.ows.xml.v100.ExceptionReport cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    at test.CSWClientDemo.main(CSWClientDemo.java:71)
```

(meanwhile, I imported org.apache.sis.xml.MarshallerPool instead of org.geotoolkit.xml.MarshallerPool.)